# Ember "setupController" in route does not work

Tags: ember.js

I am having the following code in a route mixin, in my ember up ( cofee script )

```
setupController: (controller, model)->
 @._super(controller, model)
 controller.set('total_items', this.store.metadataFor(@get('resource'))['total'])
```

The value is returned properly, but then if I try to access the "total_items" in a controller, I get "undefined". Why could be the reason behind that?

Here is the computed property, where I try to access the "total_items"

```
total_pages: (->
  if @get('total_items')
    return Math.max(1, Math.ceil( @get('total_items') / @get("per_page")))
  else
    return 1
).property("total_items", 'per_page')
```

Comment: Is the code actually being called? Did you debug to see if the value of `this.store.metadataFor(@get('resource'))['total']` is actually `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, it does. In the route it returns the "total". But in the controller, when I try to get the "total_items" (@get('total_items') ), it returns undefined.. Still could not find the reason for that.

Comment: Can you post the controller source as well?

Comment: I editted my question.

Comment: Is your controller extending from `ArrayController` or `ObjectController`?

Comment: ArrayController --
DevicesIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend RemotePaginationMixin.

Comment: Does this attribute exist in the controller or are you defining it only within `setupController`? Have to you tried to initialize it in your controller, like `total_items: 0` before you `model` runs?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see an issue with the code you've posted. If you can, please try and reproduce the issue in a JSBin.